# How do I switch between Finder tabs with a keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: finder

Ideally, I'd like to be able to cmd+1 == first tab, cmd+2 == 2nd tab, so on and so forth.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Another solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77313446) which directly creates these shortcuts.

Answer (score 33):

To move forward (Show Next Tab) through the tabs use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, to move in the reverse direction (Show Previous Tab), use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> instead.

Comment: Thanks! Works in Safari and Terminal as well!

Answer (score 20):

On a Mac, you can add custom keyboard shortcuts in

`System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`

- Pick `App Shortcuts` from the pane on the left
- Add a new shortcut with the `[+]` button
- In the popup, choose `Finder` as the Application
- In `Menu Title`, enter the exact name of the Menu Options

  - In this case "Show Next Tab" and "Show Previous Tab"
- Then perform the shortcut you want in the `Keyboard Shortcut` box

Comment: Just to confirm that you need to enter the exact name of the Menu Options which – in case your OS is set to a different language – needs to be translated accordingly (in my case German so "Show Next Tab" will be "Vorherigen Tab anzeigen" etc.)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what you mean with "Finder Tabs".

If you mean to switch between a number of tabs in your Finder Window you can do this with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and **Left** or **Right** Arrow.

If you mean to switch between opened Finder Windows on your Desktop you can do it with <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

You can change this Shortcuts in your Keyboard System Settings under the **keyboard shortcuts** Tab

Comment: Oh my gosh your my hero finally my life makes sense again 

Answer (score -2):

The first answer is quite excellent. I want to add some more.

If you split different tabs into different windows, than you can use the shortcut `` Command-`(the button on the left of 1) ``and `` Command-Shift-` `` to switch between windows you’ve got open in your current application.

Comment: The shortcut is ⌘`, not ⌘~, and as you mention, this is for switching windows, not tabs.

Comment: @grgarside yeah, they are the same button and I said this to disambiguate. I personally find it really handy

Comment: I think @grgarside is saying your answer is wrong and you should edit it to be correct.